# Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound why?

Tags: intellij-idea

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void updateHero(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Hero hero) {
        // Retrieve hero first. This is the only way to ensure hero already exists prior
        // to saving.
        Optional<Hero> currentHero = heroRepository.findById(id);
        if (currentHero == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Hero is not found for id=" + id);
        }
        LOG.debug("updateHero: modified name from {} to {}", currentHero.getName(), hero.getName());
        currentHero.setName(hero.getName());
        this.heroRepository.saveAll(currentHero);
    }
```

Why does it say at `this.heroRepository.saveAll(currentHero);`Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.example.Schnittstelle.Hero'
I cant find any solutions on google...

Comment: currentHero is of type optional, You want to save an object of class hero, you can get the value of of the hero using `currentHero.get()`

Comment: Also the saveAll expects an interable and you are sending only one element. try Sending `Collections.singletonList(currentHero.get())`

Comment: i tried earlier the class Hero, but then i get an error telling me i have to change the type of currentHero to Optional...

Comment: plus if i use Optional, there is not getname and setName() Method anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `saveAll` function expects an Iterable. The type of value which we are iterating over should be a `Hero` but in this case, you are sending an optional, that's why you got the error.

```
Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.example.Schnittstelle.Hero'
```

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void updateHero(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Hero hero) {
        // Retrieve hero first. This is the only way to ensure hero already exists prior
        // to saving.
        Optional<Hero> currentHeroOptional = heroRepository.findById(id);
        if (!currentHeroOptional.isPresent()) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Hero is not found for id=" + id);
        }
        Hero currentHero = currentHeroOptional.get();
        LOG.debug("updateHero: modified name from {} to {}", currentHero.getName(), hero.getName());
        currentHero.setName(hero.getName());
        this.heroRepository.saveAll(Collections.singletonList(currentHero));
    }
```